# `info args` in GDB in Emacs

Tags: debugging, emacs, gdb, gud

Emacs' GDB integration has the [Locals Buffer](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Other-GDB-Buffers.html) showing pretty much the result of `(gdb) info locals`. Is there way to also display the result of `(gdb) info args` of the current frame (without having to type it manually every time another frame is selected)?

Comment: aren't `args` included in `locals`?

Comment: no (at least not in GDB 7.7.1 or Emacs 24.3.1)

Comment: It looks like args are shown in the threads buffer. Look for a line like **process 4511 stopped in funcname (argname=value) of foo.c:40**. That line will automatically change as you move up and down the stack.